# How to parse a word in shell script

Tags: shell, parsing

I want to parse the following word in shell script

```
VERSION=METER1.2.1
```

Here i want to split it as two words as

```
WORD1=METER

WORD2=1.2.1
```

Let me help how to parse it?

Comment: You may use `awk` for this purpose. E.g.: `echo "METER1.2.1" | awk -F"METER" '{print $2}'`

Comment: Look at all the operators in the `Parameter Expansion` section of the `bash` man page. I'll bet some of them will be useful for this. You'll learn more if you try to figure it out yourself than if someone just does it for you here.

Comment: It's not as obvious as you may think: what is your criteria for splitting? Is it all alphabetic on the left side and then digits/dots?

Comment: By the way, as a matter of convention, only environment variables and builtins should be all-upper-case; having shell-local variables have at least one lower-case character prevents namespace conflicts between such variables and the environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Far more efficient than using external tools such is sed is bash's built-in parameter expansion support. For instance, if you want the `name` variable to contain everything until the first number, and the `numbers` variable to contain everything after the last alpha character:

```
version=METER1.2.1
name=${version%%[0-9]*}
numbers=${version##*[[:alpha:]]}
```

To understand this, see [the BashFAQ entry on string manipulation in general](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100), or [the BashFAQ entry on parameter expansion in particular](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073).

Comment: The question is not tagged `bash`, but this answer should work in any POSIX shell.